# How transform (calculate) an ordinal variable to a dichotomous in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I want to transform an ordinal variabel (0-2) – where 0 is no rights, 1 is some rights, and 2 full rights – to a dichotomous variable.

The original  ordinal variable is coded for each country and year (country-year unit).

I want to create a dichotomous variable, (let's call it *Improvement*), capturing all annual positive changes, for each country-year. So when it goes from 0 to 1 (or from 0 to 2, or from 1 to 0), I want it to be 1 for that year and country. And zero otherwise.

Below I give an example of how my data looks like. The "RIGHTS" is the original ordinal variable. The "MY DICHOTOMOUS" variable is what I want to calculate in R. How can I do it?

```
COUNTRY YEAR RIGHTS  MY DICHOTOMOUS
A        1990  0           0
A        1991  0           0
A        1992  0           0
A        1993  1           1 
A        1994  0           0
B        1990  1           1 
B        1991  1           0 
B        1992  1           0
B        1993  1           0
B        1994  1           0
```

Please, note that the original data can go the other away as well, i.e. it can go negative. I do not want to code for negative changes for this dichotomous variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `diff`

```
 df1$dichotomous <- +c(FALSE,diff(df1$RIGHTS)==1)
 df1$dichotomous
 #[1] 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: @akrun What does this `+` in `+c` do?

Comment: @762 the output is a logical vector `c(FALSE, diff(..) == 1)`  it can be converted to binary with either `as.integer` or with `+`

Answer (score 0):

Might have to do a series of `ifelse()` statements. But then again I might be miss reading your question. An example is posted below.

```
MY.DATA$MY.DICHOTOMOUS <- with(MY.DATA,ifelse(COUNTRY=="A",RIGHTS,ifelse(COUNTRY=="B"&YEAR==1990,1,factor(RIGHTS)))`
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you don't consider starting with a 1 in rights as a 1 in dichotomous:

```
x <- rights 
n <- length(x)
dichotomous <- c(0, as.numeric(x[-1] - x[-n] == 1))
```